# SVN over a directory that already exists

Tags: svn, zsh, zshrc

I've been reading about using a zsh template file on a [scientific computing website](http://sage.ucsc.edu/~wgscott/xtal/wiki/index.php/ZSH_Template_Function_Suites). I've never used subversion before but am attempting to learn how to do so. Anyhow, they have a [repository](http://code.google.com/p/zsh-templates-osx/) on Google code that has the following instructions:

> cd /Library
>   sudo svn co `http://zsh-templates-osx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Library/init`
>   cd /private
>   sudo svn co `http://zsh-templates-osx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/etc`

I have no problem with the first two lines because there is no folder located in /Library called init. The problem I'm facing is with the second two lines because /private/etc already exists along with files that I presumably need. If I run that last line, I'm afraid I'll overwrite any files located in that directory which I imagine would be disastrous.

Answer (score 1):

Those links are http links. Open them in your favorite browser and you will see what will be pulled.

Those instructions are a bit strange, especially for `/private`. I would advise you to do the following: create a directory somewhere (`/home/you/zsh-templates` for instance), and run those commands in `/home/you/zsh-templates/Library` and `.../private`). You'll get the contents there.

Once you're sure that's what you need you can either repeat those in `/Library` and `/private`, or simply copy the files from your directory to their expected destination.